Sum of Gaussian weighted modified Bessel functions of the first kind.
through the course of some calculations arising from computing a partition function in the Hubbard Model under certain conditions.
I get this expression showing up
$$
\mathcal{I}(x,\gamma) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} I_{n-m}(x)e^{-\gamma (n^2+m^2)}
$$
Or the related
$$
\mathcal{J}(x,\gamma) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} I_n(x) e^{-\gamma n^2}
$$
Where $x,\gamma$ are appropriate real numbers, and $I_n$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first kind.
For both of them I've tried using the Poisson Summation Formula with the convolution theorem to get an integral expression.
For the second one that process yielded (up to some pre-factors involving $\gamma$ I've dropped) this integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x \cos(t) - t^2/4\gamma} dt
$$
I've tried using the Generating Series and Integral Representations to simplify these sums to no avail.
Any insight on how to evaluate these would be appreciated.
